# Number of binary functions with one fixed input/output pair

Tags: combinatorics, boolean-algebra, binary

Let $A$ be the set of binary functions $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ such that

$A = \{f|f(m_1) = f(m_2)\}$

for some input $m_1, m_2 \in \{0,1\}^n.$ Further let $FUNC_n$ be the set of all binary functions over $n$ bit.

$FUNC_n := \{f | f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n\}$

Then $|FUNC_n| = 2^{n\cdot2^n}$

---

I want to prove that $\frac{|A|}{|FUNC_n|}$ is neglectable. My suggestion was that
$|A| = (2^n-1)!$, i.e. from the 2^n possible inputs I lock one and let the other be arranged "at random".

Since $|FUNC_n| = 2^{n\cdot2^n}$ I thought I can assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2^n-1)!}{2^{n\cdot2^n}}=0$.

But is that correct? For $x!$ it is obvious that it grows slower than $n^n$, but does $2^n!$ also grow slower than $n^n$ (or $2^{n\cdot2^n}$)?

Thank you for any reply or input on how to prove this!

Comment: $(2^n)!$ grows much faster than $n^n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If you plot $2^{n\cdot2^n} - (2^n)!$ the graph suggests otherwise, probably my assumption $2^{n\cdot2^n} < n^n$ was wrong

Comment: Try taking logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that $\left(2^n\right)!$ does grow slower than $2^{n2^n}$:

$$\begin{align*}
\ln\frac{\left(2^n\right)!}{2^{n2^n}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\ln k-n2^n\ln 2\\
&<\int_1^{2^n+1}\ln x\,dx-n2^n\ln 2\\
&=[x\ln x-x]_1^{2^n+1}-n2^n\ln 2\\
&=\left(2^n+1\right)\ln\left(2^n+1\right)-2^n-n2^n\ln 2\\
&<\left(2^n+1\right)\ln\left(2^n+2^n\right)-2^n-n2^n\ln 2\\
&=(n+1)\left(2^n+1\right)\ln 2-2^n-n2^n\ln 2\\
&=\left(2^n+n+1\right)\ln 2-2^n\\
&=(n+1)\ln 2-(1-\ln 2)2^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\frac{\left(2^n\right)!}{2^{n2^n}}<\frac{2^{n+1}}{\frac{e}2+e^{2^n}}<\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^{2^n}}\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0\;.$$